# AR Drone Wifi Hotspot Doesn't Appear

Tags: wifi, ros, ar.drone

I am working with the Parrot AR Drone V1.0, and even after rebooting my laptop and the drone, reseting the drone, and turning wifi on and off, the drone's wifi still does not appear in the listings for available networks? How can I fix this issue as I need to connect to the drone to stream video. I am working with ROS to program the drone so it can fly autonomously. I am also using Ubuntu 16.04 via Oracle Virtualbox on a MacBook Air 13.3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/248770/Why+is+my+drone+is+not+creating+wifi+hotspot+to+connect

Try to connect to it with your phone to see if it may be an issue only with your laptop, but check this link out for a useful answer

Comment: Thanks. So I was able to connect after doing this method: Unpair > reset > turn off > reset